# "Subscription class not found" issue with ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I use Rails 5.1.5 and I have following code.

**app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

**app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user
    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.slug
    end
    private
    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden']&.user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/channels/notifications_count_channel.rb**

```
class NotificationsCountChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
  end
end
```

JS code contains:

```
global.App.cable.subscriptions.create({ channel: 'NotificationsCountChannel',
  connected: () => {
    console.log('connected');
  },
  rejected: () => {
    console.log('rejected');
  },
  disconnected: () => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  },
  received: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

A client can successfully connect to WebSocket placed at '/cable' default path. But subscribing to NotificationsCountChannel is not successful. Here is the logs:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-24 20:50:31 +0300
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-24 20:50:31 +0300
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Subscription class not found: "NotificationsCountChannel"
```

Also I am not able to inspect `NotificationsCountChannel` in the rails console:
`NameError (uninitialized constant NotificationsCountChannel)`

It looks like Rails doesn't load NotificationsCountChannel class.
Running `bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` gives a list of paths which doesn't contain `app/channels`. It is fixable by adding
`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services)` to  config/application.rb but it doesn't solve the main problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the answer is simple: a lack of attention.
Actually `channels` dir was in the root dir of a project, not in the `app` dir.